# jQuery hide/show randomly not working?

Tags: jquery

I'm at my wit's end here. I have an .each() function that loops through and conditionally hides/shows a column in my fixed-width div. If the column is shown, the preceding column is shrunk so that everything fits, and it is expanded to its original width when the new column is hidden. My code works perfectly 80% of the time, but sometimes completely randomly it doesn't work and the new column is shown, AND the preceding one is expanded. If I just click somewhere else on the screen this is immediately fixed. What's happening??

```
function doLoop(condition) {
    if (condition) {    
        $(".utility-split-rmdr").each(function(index) {
            $(this).prev().animate({width: "97px"}, 200);
            $(this).hide();
        });
    } else {
        $(".utility-split-rmdr").each(function(index) {
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).prev().animate({width: "130px"}, 200);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: is your `condition` based on the visibility of other columns?

Comment: check value of condition in console... no way for us to know what is causing problem from code shown

Comment: Is there any way for you to make a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ - to show us what's going on / replicate the problem?

Comment: also, this whole loop of code should be completely rewritten to something like: `$(".utility-split-rmdr").each(function(index) { $(this).prev().animate({width: condition ? "97px" : "130px" }, 200); $(this).hide(); });`

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
function doLoop(condition) {
    if(!$(".utility-split-rmdr").is(':animated')) {
        if (condition) {    
            $(".utility-split-rmdr").each(function(index) {
                $(this).prev().animate({width: "97px"}, 200);
                $(this).hide();
            });
        } else {
            $(".utility-split-rmdr").each(function(index) {
                $(this).hide();
                $(this).prev().animate({width: "130px"}, 200);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This will only allow the code to be executed if none of the columns are currently being animated.

If it still breaks, at least you know it's not because of the animations interfering.